# Query the lowest temperature from single GFS forecast with GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, weather

My goal is to get the lowest temperature from a given GFS forecast.

```
// import GFS forecast collection
var gfs_dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25');

// get a single forecast
var gfs_single_forecast = gfs_dataset.first();

// select temperature measurements
var tempr = gfs_single_forecast.select('temperature_2m_above_ground');

var global_min_tempr = tempr.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: tempr.geometry(), // image footrint
  scale: tempr.projection().nominalScale() // querying at original scale
});

print(global_min_tempr);
```

The problem is that I get an error when using `reduceRegion()`:

```
Dictionary (Error)
Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image.
```

Although valid geometry is clearly provided.
What is the problem?

[Link to my code on GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa91db23a6c662febc51e55aa9178c06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try printing what you are trying to do. Your geometry is a worldwide geometry, by default it's coordinates are 'infinity'. You can show that using:

```
print(tempr.geometry().coordinates())
```

A solution would be constructing a worldwide geometry yourself ans use that as input in `reduceRegion()`. Make sure to set the `geodesic` argument to false:

```
// Worldwide geometry
var worldWideGeom = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-180, -90, 180, 90], 'EPSG:4326', false);
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b2996e414abe40bd77a8278e89d5006d)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I'm still puzzled: if you print both kinds of geometries, they return identical polygon with the only difference is that the one you suggested has a property "geodesic".

Comment: Yes, that's the part you need to change. Not sure if changing the geometry from geodesic true to false is possible. Just setting this `ee.Geometry.Rectangle()` seems more convenient.